# Defendant not present for sentencing

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, common-law, sentencing

If the defendant does not turn up to court for sentencing, can the defence still put forward mitigations and character references?

One would assume that the defence would be prevented from bringing certain positive elements up in retaliation for the defendant fleeing.

Jurisdiction: England & Wales.

Edit - I am talking about the defendant fleeing the country.

Comment: “Not turn up” and “fleeing” are different things.

Comment: Depending on the reason, they may put off the sentencing.

Comment: I meant fleeing the country, my question has been updated.

Comment: See also: Anne Sacoolas

Answer (score 8):

The defense isn’t prevented from presenting any arguments, but some arguments might be less convincing.

“My client is really sorry and will do everything he can to fix the damage and he has learnt his lesson”. “Your client just skipped bail, didn’t he?”

“My client is so sorry for this drunken attack and has since given up drinking alcohol”. “Why is Your client not here?” “He has a hangover”.

Comment: I agree with this answer and have upvoted it, but "he defense isn’t prevented from presenting any arguments," would be more convincing with some cited authority or source.

Comment: “Your client just skipped bail, didn’t he?” seems to be inviting the defence representative to act as a witness, and give evidence confirming that the client skipped bail without being sworn in.

Comment: @bdsl
 The court may take judicial notice of, and comment on, its own records. No testimony is needed. This is an interchange in the course of argument, not an invitation to testify.

Comment: What does "to skip bail" mean? It's obviously a colloquial term, but I can't make a sense of it. "He just lost the chance of getting the bail back" doesn't seem like an advantage for the accused.

Comment: @PMF It means he posted bail, which is an agreement to show up, and didn't show up.  As a consequence, his bail will be forfeit.

Comment: @Mary That's what I understood as well, but why would that be a convincing argument?

Comment: @PMF  That's a question too large and off topic for this comment thread.

Comment: You post bail so the court can assume you won’t run away. If you value your freedom more than the bail money, it’s your decision to run. As long as you make sure you are not caught again.

Comment: @bdsl The lawyer is an officer of the court and does not need to be sworn in.

Comment: In the UK nobody pays bail money (normally).